# libpng, c code, how to convert RGB value to pixel value?

Tags: c, rgb, pixel, depth, libpng

I am using libpng for C, I am new to image processing.

I use png_get_IHDR() to get the width, height, color_type and bit_depth, the values I got for an image are:

```
color_type = 6 (PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB_ALPHA)
bit_depth = 8
width = 1850
height = 2048

I use png_get_channels() to get the channels which is 4
I use png_get_rowbytes() to get the bytes per row which is 7400 (1850*4)
I use png_read_image() to get all the image data
```

My aim is to convert the RGB values to pixel value, that's all ! I know the R, G, B and Alpha values of each pixel are stored orderly in the image data buffer, seems the conversion methods are different for different bit_depth. Also can I ignore Alpha value, only use R, G, B values when doing the conversion? Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "convert the RGB values to pixel value"? Pixels are generally just RGB values. How are you defining a pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to worry about differences due to color_type and bit_depth,
and always want to ignore the alpha channel, use

```
png_set_expand(png_ptr);
png_set_strip_16(png_ptr);
if (color_type & PNG_COLOR_MASK_ALPHA)
   png_set_strip_alpha(png_ptr);
```

Then your rows will always contain 8-bit R,G,B, R,G,B ... samples,
one group of three bytes per pixel, "width" groups per row.

If you are building with libpng-1.5.6 or later, you can use
"png_set_scale_16(png_ptr)" instead; it scales 16-bit samples
down to 8-bit more accurately.